# Using MSStickerBrowserViewController with objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, imessage

I found most iMessage app tutorial about iMessage extension development is in Swift, since I am a beginner at objective-c and have to implement an iMessage extension quickly I want to code with Objective-C I find `MSStickerBrowserViewController` is some how like `UITableViewController` cause it uses a datasrouce protocol right?

So I implement my iMessage extension app like this:

```
 @interface MessagesViewController ()<MSStickerBrowserViewDataSource>
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *stickerList;
 @end
```

I have already implemented the

```
 stickerBrowserView:(MSStickerBrowserView *)stickerBrowserView stickerAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

and the

```
(NSInteger) numberOfStickersInStickerBrowserView:(MSStickerBrowserView *)stickerBrowserView
```

method and init the `stickerList` as a property of the viewController

and I think it will be fine to add a `MSStickerViewController` and made the view of it as the subview of the root view, then my work is done

```
MSStickerBrowserViewController *stickerBrowserViewController = [[MSStickerBrowserViewController alloc]initWithStickerSize:MSStickerSizeRegular];
stickerBrowserViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:stickerBrowserViewController.view];
```

But after doing that the only thing I got is a red content(which indicts the view of the MSStickerBrowserViewController did have been added into the rootview)

But none of my images were shown as a sticker

I thought there maybe lack of some hooks of the dataresource to the `MSStickerBrowserViewController`, but I can not find a delegate or resource attribute to hook them.

I also notice that there is some `override` stuff to do that with swift code, but do I have to make a subclass of `MSStrickerBrowserViewController` and implement the protocol of `MSStickerBrowserViewDataSource` in the subclass to do that?

So how to make this work, I mean with Objective-C code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with implementing the `MSStickerBrowserViewDataSource` protocol in `MessagesViewController` but then creating a separate instance of `MSStickerBrowserViewController`. That's fine so far, but as you pointed out, you're not setting the data source on `MSStickerBrowserViewController` to your class implementing the `MSStickerBrowserViewDataSource` protocol: `MessagesViewController`.

The `MSStickerBrowserViewController` class has a view of type `MSStickerBrowserView` and it's called `stickerBrowserView`. The property you're looking for is `dataSource` and described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msstickerbrowserview?language=objc). In the context of your code, that would be: `stickerBrowserViewController.stickerBrowserView.dataSource`

I could not say for certain why the Framework Engineers didn't decide call `stickerBrowserView` just `view`, and why the `stickerBrowserView` data source isn't called `delegate` but perhaps they wanted to draw a very clear distinction between the functionality of `stickerBrowserView` versus regular `UIView`.

As you allude to in your question, an alternate approach would be to sub-class `MSStickerBrowserViewController` and then implement the data-source methods in that sub-class. With the first approach, you may run into issues with having two classes that inherit from `UIViewController` being on screen at the same time. It can be done, but it's probably not necessary in this case. For your particular circumstance, I would recommend going the second route and sub-classing `MSStickerBrowserViewController` instead of using your `MessagesViewController`.

```
@interface MessagesViewController ()<MSStickerBrowserViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *stickerList;
@end

MSStickerBrowserViewController *stickerBrowserViewController = [[MSStickerBrowserViewController alloc]initWithStickerSize:MSStickerSizeRegular];
stickerBrowserViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

// Missing Line
stickerBrowserViewController.stickerBrowserView.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:stickerBrowserViewController.view];
```